# Sublime Text 3 Linter Problems

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

Last week I found this awesome text editor "Sublime Text 3" and I love the plugins.

Everything is working except the SublimeLinter plugin and the plugins that add language specific linting to it.

I have a problem with PHP and JavaScript working together with the following:

php does work but I dont know how to get JavaScript to work.
For php what I did is go to Pref>pac set>Sublime Linter>Settings-User
Then I set the following:

```
 "paths": { "linux": [], "osx": [], "windows": [ "C:/Users/**/Documents/php-5.5.11-nts-Win32-VC11-x86/" ] },
```

(in the ** is my pc name)

That is working perfectly. But I know I have to install node.js that is what I have done.

I made a build system:

```
{   "cmd": ["C:/Program Files/nodejs", "$file"],   "selector": "source.js"   }
```

It is not working, and did this one too:

```
{   "cmd": ["node", "$file"],   }
```

I have installed: sublimelinter, sublimelinter-php, sublimelinter-jsl, and sublimelinter-jshint.

It would be very nice if you could explain everything step by step what to do to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Each independent linter plugin for [SublimeLinter 3](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter3) has its own dependencies/prerequisites. I would strongly recommend you to read carefully its specific installation and settings instructions on GitHub and the relevant SublimeLinter 3 new documentation if necessary, especially as this plugin was widely rewritten for Sublime Text 3.

For instance, your Windows [SublimeLinter-php](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-php) configuration seems correct: you just made your linter executable (here: php) directory available to SublimeLinter via your user settings, whatever your system `PATH` settings, which is the quickest and usually the easiest method.

On the other hand, the [SublimeLinter-jshint](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-jshint) plugin definetely requires besides its own installation (with Sublime Package Manager):

1. properly installing Node.js and NPM: just grab and launch the latest Windows installer (msi file), which will setup both;
2. and installing the jshint package via your terminal: `npm install -g jshint`.

It is pretty straightforward: your linter will work right after a Sublime Text restart. If need be, you will just have to configure jshint "lintering options" (most probably using .jshintrc files, without any Sublime Linter user setting needed).

Configuring sublimelinter-jsl is anothe case. It requires installing the relevant executable i.e. [JavaScript Lint](http://javascriptlint.com/download.htm) (which is **not** a node package), and ensuring that its path is available to SublimeLinter.